# How to end a conversation?

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I've created a bot using Bot Framework and I am using the `conversationID` to maintain state with my back end conversation engine.  I can't find in the documentation for ending the conversation.  It's imperative that, at some point, the user be able to signal an "end, or exit" to the conversation so that the next time they start a conversation, it gets a new `conversationID`.  It should be a simple task, I would think.  I'm using the default echo template and just replaced the count the number of letters line with a method to my class, which returns the text to send back to the user.

Comment: Please don't use hashtags on the Stack Exchange network. (Apparently their documentation tells you to do that, ugh...)

Comment: Documentation no longer references hashtags on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is now an ActivityTypes.EndOfConversation (this is already in the sdk).

Here is one way to use it:
v3

```
public static async Task EndConversation(this IBotToUser botToUser, string code = EndOfConversationCodes.CompletedSuccessfully, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    var message = botToUser.MakeMessage();
    message.Type = ActivityTypes.EndOfConversation;
    message.AsEndOfConversationActivity().Code = code;

    await botToUser.PostAsync(message, cancellationToken);
}
```

This should also be in a future release: [GitHub Pull Request](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/pull/2678/files/f2b6ece2d54c408e4b0d78b6bd4878fc14496cb3#diff-daab248c30b725ede1a1a7141d6b3ec3)

---

v4

```
public static async Task EndConversation(this ITurnContext turnContext, string code = EndOfConversationCodes.CompletedSuccessfully, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    var endOfConversation = Activity.CreateEndOfConversationActivity();
    endOfConversation.Code = code;
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(endOfConversation, cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: I think this is for v3 not v4. IBotToUser is not supported in v4 Bot Framework. How to use it in v4 please?

Comment: @noobprogrammer i've updated the answer with a v4 example

Answer (score 0):

A json web tokens(jwt) are available in one chat only. so it gets converstionId again.
The session.endConversation() method provides a convenient method for quickly terminating a conversation with a user. is used for end the conversation.

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no session.endConversation() in the .Net framework.  That is why I posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a newer, shorter way[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.extensions.endconversation?view=botbuilder-3.12.2.4):

```
context.EndConversation(EndOfConversationCodes.CompletedSuccessfully);
```