# How to end a conversation in msbot sdk v4 using node js

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am developing a bot in microsoft sdk v4 using node js. I am unable to end the conversation using ActivityTypes.EndofConversation. Please provide some solution.

Comment: You should check out this post, I guess. hope this helps. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43657463/how-to-end-a-conversation/43658800

Comment: Can you post how you're trying to end your dialog? The full code snippet?

Comment: @TejasBramhecha this is related to c# where as I am using msbot sdk v4 node js

Comment: @JJ_Wailes I am not using dialogs. I didn't implement it in v4. I am asking how to implement the following v3 code in v4 using node js
"session.endConversation("Thank you for your business!");"

Comment: In order for anyone to be able to help you, you have to post the code of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You never posted any code to show what you've tried so far, so I'm going to go out on a limb and assume you mean the following:

V3:

```
function (session, result, next) {
        //stuff
        session.endConversation("Nice to meet you.")
    }
```

V4:

```
async functionName(step) {
        //stuff
        await step.context.sendActivity("Nice to meet you.");
        await step.endDialog();
    }
```